# AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'runandwait'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, attributeerror, pyttsx3

The program below is giving me an error. This is my program:

```py
import pyttsx3 as tts

def speak(text):
    engine = tts.init("sapi5")
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runandwait()

speak('Hello user this is a test message.')
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\SIDDHESH\Projects\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    speak('Hello user this is a test message.')
  File "c:\Users\SIDDHESH\Projects\test.py", line 5, in speak
    engine.runandwait()
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'runandwait'
```

I would like to point out that my variable is called `engine` but the error message says something about a variable `'Engine'`. I would also like to point out that I am using **Visual Studio Code** to run my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to write `engine.runAndWait()`, starting every new word with an uppercase letter. Remember that python is case sensitive, it means that `runandwait` and `runAndWait` are different attributes.